# Python function to add a tuple to MySql not working

Tags: python, mysql

I'm trying to add an entry into mysql database from python. I don't get any errors when the code is executed, but the entry just doesn't appear in the database. Not sure where i'm going wrong. The columns in my cities table in mysql are city, state

```
mydb = mysql.connector.connect(**config)
mycursor = mydb.cursor()
print('type city')
city = input()
print('type state')
state = input()
insert = "insert into cities values('{0}', '{1}')".format(city, state)
mycursor.execute(insert)
mycursor.close()
```

Comment: Have you tried adding connection.commit()?

Comment: @WilliamYang that worked! thanks much

Comment: Avoid SQL injection using [execute](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-execute.html) to contain parameters, never string format.

Answer (score 0):

Remember to commit `mydb.commit()` and it should work.

@danblack fixed sql injection

```
mydb = mysql.connector.connect(**config)
mycursor = mydb.cursor()
print('type city')
city = input()
print('type state')
state = input()

stmt = "INSERT INTO cities VALUES('%s', '%s');"
cursor.execute(stmt, (city, state)) 

mycursor.execute(insert)
mydb.commit()
```

Cheers